# Scanning QR code from screen

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to read a QR code that appears on the device screen but I cannot find any library that does it without taking a screenshot first.
I know that using `zxing` it is possible to scan the QR code from an image, but is there any way to do the scan on runtime when the QR code appears in the device screen?

Comment: Can you generate the image programmatically then send it to zxing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android

Answer (score 2):

You might try [Google's Mobile Vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview).

The [detect](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/BarcodeDetector.html#detect(com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame)) method only requires a Frame, which you can [build from a Bitmap](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/Frame.Builder).

Answer (score 1):

Consider generating the screenshot programmatically (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651242/1240523), loading the image as a bitmap and using that in conjunction with zxing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a project which allows this called [Zxing Android Embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded). Take a look at the [Embedding](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/EMBEDDING.md) documentation.

There's also an [Activity](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java) which they provide as a sample using their `DecoratedBarcodeView`.

It's embedded, and can be added in the XML as shown [here](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/50e3acce091decc195f67e6079b86427ddc2ad60/sample/src/main/res/layout/continuous_scan.xml#L6), namely:

```
    <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView
        android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonsLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
```